# Watchkit:Integrate watch project with main iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2

I had to create a watchkit project for my clients for an existing iPhone app. Since I didn't have the main iPhone app project with me, I created a seperate project and implemented my watch codes in it. Now I have to integrate this project with the main project. Is there any direct way to this or should I create new targets in the main app and then copy my files one by one.

Comment: Yes you should create a target on companion app and then add all your files to new watchkit project. I already did it and that's fine.

Comment: So I should delete the files created automatically while adding the targets and then add my files to it. Then import it in xcode right?

Comment: Yes, you already have these files so it will be fine to replace